# Rails: Disable Rollbar in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rollbar

I'm using Rollbar for error tracking in my Rails app. For some reason I'm getting errors from my localhost (in development). In config/initializers/rollbar.rb:

```
unless Rails.env.production?
    config.enabled = false
  end
```

Anything else I need to be doing?

Full rollbar.rb file:

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|

  config.access_token = Figaro.env.rollbar_key

  # Here we'll disable in 'test':

  unless Rails.env.production?
    config.enabled = false
  end

end
```

Comment: Please include the entire rollbar.rb file along with the stacktrace?

Comment: @JoshDeeden see edit with full rollbar.rb file. Not sure what you mean by stacktrace since it's not a specific error but all my errors which are being reported in rollbar (occurrence stems from localhost)

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood the question.    Strange.   That looks correct.   What happens when you move the `config.access_token` bit into the `unless` block?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Now you will get notified only when an exception happens in production.

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|

  config.access_token = ENV['ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN']

  if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
    config.enabled = false
  end

  config.environment = ENV['ROLLBAR_ENV'].presence || Rails.env
end
```